# Helpful articles on the subject of managing programmers?

Tags: productivity, management, teamwork

What are the most helpful articles on the subject of managing programmers? I came across this one recently, and thought it was excellent -

[The unspoken truth about managing geeks](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9137708/Opinion_The_unspoken_truth_about_managing_geeks)

What else is out there?

Comment: If you haven't read all the books written by [Steve McConnell](http://www.stevemcconnell.com/), I advise you drop everything and do so. Not only will it teach you a thing or two about managing programmers, but it will make *you* a better programmer yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rands (in Repose)](http://randsinrepose.com/) talks about this. He also took excerpts from his blog and put them in book form: Managing Humans.

Answer (score 6):

E.g.: http://www.randsinrepose.com/archives.html

The best thing you can do IMO is to read Gerald M. Weinberg books.

Being a "new user" (actually a long time lurker) I'm allowed to post one link only, so I'll try to sneak in this one: http://www.ayeconference.com)

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to Joel's [articles](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/) (Tech Lead section), I find it really useful.

Answer (score 2):

Although 9 years old, I found [Managing Software Engineers](http://philip.greenspun.com/ancient-history/managing-software-engineers) to be a helpful resource.

I do feel that people working in these careers work best under management styles of Theory Y or even Theory Z.  Both of these take the approach that treating employees well promotes success.

There is a 2005 article on the concepts of [Theory P](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/irm-blog/theory-p-the-philosophy-of-managing-programmers-4993), a management style concocted by some management consultant for managing programmers.  The name may sound cool, but don't let it fool you!  It reeks of Theory X style management and is quite insulting to the programming profession as a whole.

Lastly, here is a handy [translation guide so managers can understand when programmers give them certain answers](http://blog.tomevslin.com/2005/03/managing_progra.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Rands in Repose](http://randsinrepose.com/) has already been mentioned by maksa, so I'll throw in his book [Managing Humans](http://www.managinghumans.com/) which is an excellent (and amusing) read about what you need to know about managing software developers.

It's also a nice read for developers who want to know what managers actually have to deal with and what they do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a dev who is moving up the food chain, then [Herding Cats](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590590171) is a great read aimed at that situation.

Comment: What's with the random minus?